# Paypal: mixing digital & physical items in select form button

Tags: paypal, button

Okay, I am working on a publishing site, and want users to select paperback or digital from the button dropdown "Add to Cart" button. So far, so good—I've managed that just fine.

But of course the problem is that I want to charge shipping on physical items but not on digital items. I haven't found any way so far to specify that one option in the dropdown is no shipping while the other is not.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Shipping rates are going to be based on one of the following: total order amount, total order weight, or total item quantity. So for your scenario, based on the information that you provided, I would choose to use **total order weight**, and simply do not assign a weight; or assign a weight of zero for the digital items that you are selling.

Because you want to charge for the actual items you are shipping, you will need to create a rule based on weight (lb or kg - just be consistent for each one) which will trigger a shipping charge that you selected. For example: total weight over .25lbs but less than 5lbs = $10.00, or whatever you deem appropriate.

To get started, login to your paypal account and click on the "My Account" tab, click profile, and then My Selling Tools. On the "Profile" page, Click on "My Selling Tools" on the left side of the page.

Scroll down to the “Shipping my items” section and find "Shipping calculations". Click on "Update" for that row.

*Make sure you include all of the States that you ship to & currencies that you accept. For complete and detailed instructions, please try this link: https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/get-started/shipping-calculator. Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks, Josh. That has possibilties, but.... The question is whether I can include a shipping weight inside a dropdown option.

Comment: What would be the benefit of including weight in a dropdown vs. simply assigning it to the product?

Comment: The problem is that Paypal's dropdown options do not allow for different products per se, so differences have to be settled at the option level.